# Google map is not rendered fully in the div?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Here I have the `map_canvas` within a `div` called `map`.  The thing is when I increase the `width` of the `map`, the google map in one side is not rendered fully.

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The width of the map-area is increasing but the right side of the map is not rendering fully.

When you change the size of the div, trigger the resize event on the map:

[from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map):

**Events**

resize -    Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') .

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the width of the div container has been set? Also, has the width of the map been set in the mapOptions object?

If you provide more examples of your code, it will be easier to help.

Comment: <div id="map-area" class="grid_16" style="width: 740px; height:755px; float: left; margin:0px auto">
   <div class="item rounded dark" style="background: white; padding: 0px; margin: 0px 4px; border: 2px solid #CCC">
        <div id="map_canvas" class="map rounded" style="height: 755px; top:0px; left:0px; z-index: 1"></div>
        </div>
        </div>

Comment: Have you tried setting a width on map_canvas? Either 100% or inherited or something like that? In this scenario, using the Inspector in Chrome will help a lot, play around with the width values on each div and see if it helps your problem.

Comment: Within the css file, I have both width and height as 100%.

Comment: Well you're also setting widths in the DOM, I'd avoid setting them both in the DOM and CSS files, you;ll have conflicts and it will make things confusing.

Comment: The width of the `map-area` is increasing but the right side of the map is not rendering fully.