# Half grey google map while dynamically creating it for more then once with javascript live function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, jquery

Our code starts with live function and whole page content is created by js live function,below code used for creating google maps within javascript code, for the first creation everything is fine (map seems correctly on screen) but after that time when google map is created again at the same page half of the map comes up and half is grey, that is our problem.

JQuery version 1.8.0

Bootstrap version 2.2.2

```
var idz = 'mapg';
tr.append($('<td>').append($('<div>', {
'id': idz,
'style': 'width: 100%; height: 300px'
})));
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.988921, 29.021326);
var options = {
   zoom: 10,
   center: latlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
rootMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(idz), options);
```

[image: google map problem screen]

I would appreciate any help with this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too had the same problem, I solved it by triggering the `resize` of Google maps.

Here is the below code:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(rootMap , 'resize'); //For v3
```

Add this after initializing the Google maps.

You can take a look at this [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682514/google-map-is-not-rendered-fully-in-the-div).

Comment: With your response and below code we solved the problem thank you google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(rootMap, 'idle', function(){
google.maps.event.trigger(rootMap , 'resize');
});