# Google maps api not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm playing around with [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) and our company has its own API key for google maps. a co-worker and I tried to get the maps to work - Well in full screen the following code worked - by that I mean we just let the map scale the full width of the browser, the code we used is:

```
<script>
    var map;

    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Obviously their is no API key because that's loaded else where.

So I decided to add on to this, because I needed the map stored else where - and I added this extra jazz:

```
<style>
    #map-canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #Map{
        height: 350px;
    }
</style>
```

The first one is obvious, The second one is part of the jquery-ui tab which I basically, for this tab, set it's height to 350px

Moving on - the issue is this:

[image]

if I drop a person on to the road then I get:

[image]

the "up close and personal" stalker look goes full width and height but the far away directions map is all broken....

Anyone know why?

Comment: what are you using as your map container then? `map-canvas` or `Map`?

Comment: sorry that should been more clear - `map-canvas` - the above code is from a partial that is rendered into the page containing the div `Map`

Comment: Is the "Map" div initially hidden? How is it's width specified? Looks like when it is rendered the API gets zero size for that div (which gives the tiles in the top left corner behavior).

Comment: The `Map` div has a height of 350px; its width is auto.  should I specify its width as like 100%?

Comment: @geocodezip I updated the op to state: The second one is part of the jquery-ui tab which I basically, for this tab, set it's height to 350px - This describes the Map div.

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this issue? Having the same problem here. The map is in a tabbed page where the map is hidden when loaded.

Comment: did anyone got a solution to this problem yet, I tried to trigger the resize event however nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem, where half of my map stayed grey colored(menas: **unavailable state**) whenever I resized the Google Maps container.  I solved it by *triggering the **`refresh`** event of Google maps*  like this

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

**FYI:** *Whenever you change the Google Maps height or width, it is better to trigger this resize event.*

> **`resize`** :    Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: **`google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`**.

You can also check my question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682514/google-map-is-not-rendered-fully-in-the-div).

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: That didn't work.... The map is still the same - I am calling it after `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` if I then call it before then the map never shows up....

Comment: Still nothing - if I let the page load, then in the console call it - the map shows properly...

Comment: @LogicLooking Ok.  can you try this `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){ google.maps.event.trigger(map , 'resize'); });` after `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Comment: Didn't work, also: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined ` now is thrown in the console. How ever if I just paste `google.maps.event.trigger(map , 'resize');` in the console - it just works....

Answer (score 1):

Good point praveen!
Even I *had* same problem!
You don't have to call it only when the div or window is resized! In my case I am calling it after the Map is rendered.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

Now I can see full rendered screen!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be a comment to the other answer?

Comment: ya true but I need 50 reputations to even comment :(

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout when the DOM is ready. This is specifically for the maps that are initially hidden (Like when you are using the map inside a modal or popup window).

In jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout('initialize()', 2000);

});
```