# Google Maps Failing to render

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

**Note:** I thought it would be better to make a new question on this.

So I recently asked a question about [why Google maps is not rendering properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601227/google-maps-api-not-working-properly). Now the answer would seem straight forward and simple, accept my code looks like this:

```
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The issue is the map is still broken:

[image]

This map is stored in a `<div id="Map"></div>` which has a height of 350. This Div that holds the map is part of Jquery-UI Tabs, so it also has jquery skinning attached to it which may affect things like size and so on.

With that said the map should just work.

If I open the console and throw in: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` the maps then works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a Google Map (v3) embedded within a jQuery UI Tabs, and had to work around the issue with this fix:

```
var initialized = false;

$('.tabs').find('.ui-tabs-nav li').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('a').text() === 'Location') {
        if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
            initialize();
            initialized = true;
        } else {
            $(this).click(function() {
                if(!initialized) {
                    initialize();
                    initialized = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

*Note* that `initialize()` should run your starting map code. There are lots of ways to slice-and-dice the initialization, but the point is that we don't do it until the tab we're looking for ("Location", in this case) is active.

Comment: I apologize I'm not really sure where this would go or how to implement it with my google maps stuff >.> I see the general underlying principle just not how to implement it.

Comment: Instead of initializing the entire map everytime the Tab is active, why not just initialize the map on page load then trigger the resize (`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`) when the map tab is active?

Comment: @SuviVignarajah Do you have an example?

Comment: Sure - if you put together a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have, I can put in my suggested fix for you.

Comment: Thanks @SuviVignarajah - as long as you keep the `initialized` variable, it will only initialize once - with the added bonus of not initializing _at all_ if the tab is never activated.

Comment: @SuviVignarajah I wouldn't even know how to replicate this in js fiddle :( There so much underlying logic behind everything.

Comment: @jterry ahh ok I see how it works. So this code is run when the page loads, and checks to see if the Location tab is active first - otherwise sets up a click handler for the tab to initialize the map.