# Google maps - map doesn't reload when user shares location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map that displays correctly on the initial page load, and shows the correct place markers (which are retrieved from a custom web service).  However I'm prompting the user to share their location, and when they do this the map disappears.  I'm prompting the user to share their location by using:

```
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition, error);
        } ...
```

This works fine, and in the 'success' function that gets called (setPosition), I use the following to refresh the map:

```
//load map object and show map
this.map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById(this.mapElementId),
{
zoom: this.currentZoom,
center: this.startPos,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
);
```

'this.map' is successfully populated with a google map object. The 'document.getElementById(this.mapElementId)' works fine and finds the `<div>` that I want the map to appear in, and the 'currentZoom' and the co-ordinates for 'startPos' are being correctly obtained.

This was all working fine previously when the map was part of an `<iframe>` - I've now moved the code inline into the page that previously contained the `<iframe>` (it doesn't look like a cross-domain issue, as I've verified this)

**UPDATE**

(Actually, please ignore my previous update - the markup I'm getting differs depending whether or not I'm debugging.  Here is the markup from the working and broken versions when I allow sharing of my location, without having the Firebug debugger running.  The blue line in the 'working' version shown highlights the div that contains the Google map.):

WORKING:

[image]
BROKEN:

[image]

Comment: I guess refreshing Google after getting the user's geolocation might work.  Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18607307/1671639) how to trigger refresh in Google maps v3.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Actully forget to ask you, is map-canvas is in grey color?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my 'setPosition' callback function (used when the browser has been able to successfully request the user's geolocation), I'm hiding a `<div>` that shows an error message when the geolocation request is unsuccessful.  For some reason, hiding the `<div>`  stops the map from displaying even though it isn't subsequently referenced in any code, and isn't related to the `<div>` that contains the Google map.  I've asked a separate question about what may be going on, and how to reliably clear the error message here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134180/jquery-javascript-hiding-div-stops-google-map-from-appearing